# Unable to update Homebrew on MacOS El Capitan

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

To integrate my KeePassX with my browse I tried to follow this guide:
http://dareneiri.github.io/Setting-Up-KeePassX-With-Autologin/

but I continously ran into new problems. I had homebrew installed (maybe before a new setup of my system) but didn't use it for some time. So when I tried to do:
brew install qt cmake libgcrypt zlib libmicrohttpd

I received the following error:

> Error: undefined method `desc' for Zlib:Class

I found out that this might be an update problem, so I tried
brew update

which gave me:

> fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/.git/index.lock': Permission denied

How to fix the permission issues? I cannot uninstall and install for the same reason.

brew doctor gives me:

```
AnkeNowsMacBook:keepassx-master anke$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.3) is outdated
Please install XQuartz 2.7.7:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/librtmp.dylib

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    autoconf
    autoconf (vom alten Mac)
    automake
    automake (vom alten Mac)
    git (vom alten Mac)
    libgpg-error (vom alten Mac)
    libksba (vom alten Mac)
    libtool
    libtool (vom alten Mac)
    libyaml (vom alten Mac)
    makedepend (vom alten Mac)
    openssl (vom alten Mac)
    pkg-config (vom alten Mac)
    readline (vom alten Mac)
Error: Failed to import: apple-gcc42
undefined method `desc' for AppleGcc42:Class
Error: Failed to import: awk
undefined method `desc' for Awk:Class
Error: Failed to import: bc
undefined method `desc' for Bc:Class
Error: Failed to import: bzip2
undefined method `desc' for Bzip2:Class
Error: Failed to import: diffstat
undefined method `desc' for Diffstat:Class
Error: Failed to import: diffutils
undefined method `desc' for Diffutils:Class
Error: Failed to import: ed
undefined method `desc' for Ed:Class
Error: Failed to import: expect
undefined method `desc' for Expect:Class
Error: Failed to import: file-formula
undefined method `desc' for FileFormula:Class
Error: Failed to import: gpatch
undefined method `desc' for Gpatch:Class
Error: Failed to import: gperf
undefined method `desc' for Gperf:Class
Error: Failed to import: grep
undefined method `desc' for Grep:Class
Error: Failed to import: groff
undefined method `desc' for Groff:Class
Error: Failed to import: gzip
undefined method `desc' for Gzip:Class
Error: Failed to import: heimdal
undefined method `desc' for Heimdal:Class
Error: Failed to import: krb5
undefined method `desc' for Krb5:Class
Error: Failed to import: lapack
undefined method `desc' for Lapack:Class
Error: Failed to import: less
undefined method `desc' for Less:Class
Error: Failed to import: libedit
undefined method `desc' for Libedit:Class
Error: Failed to import: libiconv
undefined method `desc' for Libiconv:Class
Error: Failed to import: libpcap
undefined method `desc' for Libpcap:Class
Error: Failed to import: lsof
undefined method `desc' for Lsof:Class
Error: Failed to import: m4
undefined method `desc' for M4:Class
Error: Failed to import: make
undefined method `desc' for Make:Class
Error: Failed to import: nano
undefined method `desc' for Nano:Class
Error: Failed to import: ncurses
undefined method `desc' for Ncurses:Class
Error: Failed to import: openldap
undefined method `desc' for Openldap:Class
Error: Failed to import: openssh
undefined method `desc' for Openssh:Class
Error: Failed to import: rsync
undefined method `desc' for Rsync:Class
Error: Failed to import: screen
undefined method `desc' for Screen:Class
Error: Failed to import: srm
undefined method `desc' for Srm:Class
Error: Failed to import: tcl-tk
undefined method `desc' for TclTk:Class
Error: Failed to import: tcpdump
undefined method `desc' for Tcpdump:Class
Error: Failed to import: units
undefined method `desc' for Units:Class
Error: Failed to import: unzip
undefined method `desc' for Unzip:Class
Error: Failed to import: whois
undefined method `desc' for Whois:Class
Error: Failed to import: zlib
undefined method `desc' for Zlib:Class

Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated.
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours. This is a long time in brewland!
To update Homebrew, run `brew update`.
```

I see some redundancys, but I don't know what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that everything under `/usr/local` belongs to the group `admin`:

```
chgrp -R admin /usr/local
chmod -R g+w /usr/local
```

Allow anyone from the group `admin` to write anything in `/usr/local`

```
chgrp -R admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
chmod -R g+w /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

The undefined method `desc` means that your Homebrew is outdated. Once you change the permissions, try running `brew update` again.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
When I try 

chgrp -R admin /usr/local

I basically do get 

operation not permitted..

find full output here:
http://dpaste.com/2SKGYH1

any hint?

Comment: Try running `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local` instead of `chgrp`. If that still says permission denied, I'd try reinstalling homebrew.

Comment: After doing everything you suggested here is what I got:
AnkeNowsMacBook:~ anke$ brew update
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

Comment: Can I just reinstall homebrew without uninstalling the previous version?

Comment: It looks like it failed to update due to a networking error. Are you using a VPN connection? To reinstall homebrew you will need to first uninstall it to install it again.

Comment: VPN! That solved the problem ..( I tried from university)
At home everything worked fine and I was able to update properly. Thanks for all your help!!!